# When to switch from storing nested component variables in this.props vs this.state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm getting back into React and trying to replicate an instagram post. Variables that don't change such as the name of the poster, location, etc I think I have a solid understanding of how to handle. I keep in them in the chain of `this.props` as they will be immutable from the user perspective. But when it comes to something like "reactions", I am unsure of when to begin storing them in `this.state` vs. `this.props` due to the *multiple* levels of nesting.

Should I keep the data relating to my reactions array / object in `this.state` (as I attempt to do below) for all nested components *all the way down*? Or keep them in `this.props` until I get to the lowest child component?

I don't have any code for lifting state up since I want to make sure my architecture is correct first.

**Home.js**

```
const POST_DATA = [
  {
    name: 'Outdoors Guy',
    location: 'Yosemite, CA',
    id: '123',
    body: 'Hello world!',
    image: 'https://someurl',
    reactions: [
      {
        reaction: 'Like',
        count: 2,
        selected: true
      },
      {
        reaction: 'Love',
        count: 1,
        selected: false
      }
    ]  
  }
];

export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        posts: POST_DATA
    }
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
        <ScrollView>
            <FlatList styles={styles.list}
              data={this.state.posts}
              renderItem={({ item }) =>  
              <Post
                name={item.name}
                location={item.location}
                body={item.body}
                image={item.image}
                reactions={item.reactions}/>}
                keyExtractor={item => item.id}/>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**Post.js**

```
export default class Post extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        state = {
            // should I be doing this?
            reactions: this.props.reactions
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <View style={styles.postHeader}>
                    // Example of these two variables ending their chaining here
                    <Text style={styles.name}>{this.props.name}</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.location}>{this.props.location}</Text>
                </View>
                <Text style={styles.body}>{this.props.body}</Text>
                <Image style={styles.image} source={{uri: this.props.image}}/>
                // Heres where the confusion begins
                <ReactionList list={this.props.reactions}/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

**ReactionList.js**

```
export default class ReactionList extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        state = {
            reactions: this.props.reactions
        }
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.reactions === null)
        {
            return (
                <View>
                    <AddReaction/>
                    <FlatList styles={styles.reactionList}
                        data={this.state.reactions}
                        renderItem={({ item }) =>  
                        <Reaction
                            reaction={item.reaction}
                            count={item.count}
                            selected={item.selected}/>}
                            keyExtractor={item => item.id}/>
                </View>
              )
        }
        else{
            return (
            <View>
                <AddReaction/>
            </View>
            )
        }
    }
}
```

**Reaction.js**

```
export default class Reaction extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        state = {
            // I understand these are not visible in the component 
            // but still want to track the data
            count: this.props.count,
            selected: this.props.selected
        }
    }

    _onSelectPress () {
            this.setState({ 
                selected: !this.state.selected,
                count: ++this.state.count
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.reaction}
                onPress={() => this._onSelectPress()}>
                <Text style={styles.reactionText}>{this.props.reaction}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it makes sense to you, you could store the `POST_DATA` completely inside the state, as this will greatly simplify how the Parent component who holds the post information and the Child Post component behave.

For example, what if, instead of just letting the user edit reactions, you wanted the post owner to be able to edit the body or location of `POST_DATA`? Or what if you wanted the reactions count to be accesible to say, a separate modal (when you click on the post)?

A way to future-proof this design, while keeping it simple, is to send the whole `POST_DATA` to your `<Post>` component and if you don't want to use a library such as Redux to handle the state, then lift the callback for edits up:

*[Here's a simplified Codesandbox I did of this implementation](https://codesandbox.io/embed/mystifying-feynman-xruzn?fontsize=14).*

```
<InstaPost
  post={this.state.post}               <-- this.state.post holds POST_DATA 
  handleReactionClick={this.handleReactionClick}
  handleBodyEdit={this.handleBodyEdit} <-- if we decide to implement this later on
/>
```

#### Why hold network data as an Immutable object in the app/component state?

The benefits of holding the post data in the state, as an Immutable object (in the example I used immer.js), is that if, for example, the way Instagram or Facebook work is that, when you click on the "Love" reaction, an API request is sent for your reaction, and it returns the value of the reactions updated real-time:

So for example, if I pressed on "Like (2)", and 10 more people pressed like before that, the API wouldn't return "3" (2+1), but rather, "13" (2 + 1 + 10). Handling this with your current design would require much more work than with the design I propose.

Personally, I would prefer using a library such as Redux for application state, but for a small prototype it's not necessary. I do, however, recommend always using immutable objects whatever the size of the project if network fetching/updating is involved.

Hope this helps!

Comment: 1) The plan is to do a GET req for the list of posts in `componentDidMount` and set the post array to be in state. (POST_DATA will be an array of posts passed to FlatList data) 2) Instagram's UI doesn't update in real time, when you like a post, the database is updated with your action, but you manually have to refresh to see the addition of other likes. I think this allows them to simplify their rerendering code. 3) I looked in to Redux, but want to do the pure React form to ensure I have a solid understanding before moving on.

Comment: Regardless of the need to update in real-time or not, as you say, when you fetch the posts on mount, they will end up in the state, hence the best way is to simply pass the individual post to the child component as a prop, and have a callback to the parent to update the post.

And, as I said, any action that you want to implement later on (such as editing a post), in the future, is easier with this implementation instead of later on having to copy the body of the post to the child state. Cheers!

Comment: Ok, so here’s my final question: Is my convention of getting the post data into the InstaPost state correct? I.e in the InstaPost constructor? Should I be doing in InstaPost state = { postData: this.props.post} ?

Comment: And I guess, to summarize, your suggestion is to use state all the way down the component chain, correct?